# Deep copy: Orika vs SerializationUtils

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy, orika

In an entity `MyEntity` I found something like this

```
@Override
public MyEntity clone(){
    // TODO: do not use Orika here
    MyEntity clone = new DefaultMapper().map(this, MyEntity.class);
    clone.setFieldA(null);
    clone.setFieldB(null);
    return clone;
}
```

with `DefaultMapper` being an orika-mapper:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DefaultMapper extends ConfigurableMapper {

}
```

Is it legit to use orika for a deep copy? Or should one rather use SerializationUtils to achieve this?

The reason for the `TODO` is: Everytime we call `clone()` orika uses reflection to calculate the actual mapping. Sadly we cannot use injection because we are inside an entity.

We could as well make a constructor in which we map every single field by hand. This is no solution here because there are many fields with deep nesting. Furthermore, if a new column is added, there is a high risk of forgetting to adjust the mapping.

Do you have any better solution than to use orika?
Is SerializationUtils an alternative at all?

Comment: Could you not serve the DefaultMapper as a singleton with a factory in this case?

Comment: I was wrong in telling that `new DefaultMapper()` ist the problem. Actually it is not a problem to instantiate it always with new. The problem is the mapping. This is where the reflection happens. I will update my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orika is way faster. On 10000 map-iterations orika needed 3 ms to map my object. SerializationUtils needed over 3 **seconds** to do the same. Furthermore, orika has a cache for already mapped objects. Of course this uses more metaspace. It depends on the situation but overall orika is a better solution in my case.